# Search for all combinations of first, middle and last name

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database there is a table called `author`, which 4 columns:

- authorID
- firstName
- middleName
- lastName

A user, for example, is searching for Edgar Allan Poe. In our table Edgar Allan Poe is saved as: **firstName**- Edgar, **middleName** - Allan and **lastName** - Poe. This query is pretty straightforward. But how to write a query that matches not only Edgar Allan Poe, but also Poe Allan Edgar, Edgar Poe, Allan Poe, Edgar Allan, Allan Edgar Poe without writing all these possible combinations on our own? Also when the user is searching, he/she is searching as 'Edgar Allan Poe' or 'Poe Allan Edgar' altogether, not in a separate fields.

Comment: Are _all_ combinations acceptable?

Comment: @Manngo Yes, all combinations are acceptable.

Comment: Should `Edgar Allan Allan` be considered a match?  Also, do you have any protocols regarding two-part names, such as `von Bach` in `Karl Ignatius von Bach`?

Comment: @toonice Yes, **Edgar Allan Allan** should also be considered a match, as well as **'Edgar Poe xyz'** or **'Allan Poe'**. Basically, if at least two of the three columns(**firstName**, **middleName**, **lastName**) are somewhere in the user query, it should be considered a match. We don't have any protocols when it comes to the two-part names, so I guess the query for  Karl Bach won't work.

Comment: What about `Allanah Poelsen`?

Comment: @toonice No, it shouldn't be considered a match. I forgot to mention, they should be separated by space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SimilarNames;
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE SimilarNames( authorFullName VARCHAR( 250 ) )
    BEGIN
        SET @authorFullNameCommad = CONCAT( '\'',
                                            REPLACE( authorFullName,
                                                     ' ',
                                                     '\', \'' ),
                                            '\'' );

        SET @selectStatementString := CONCAT( "SELECT authorID,",
                                              "       firstName,",
                                              "       middleName,",
                                              "       lastName ",
                                              "FROM author ",
                                              "WHERE ( ( firstName IN ( ",
                                              @authorFullNameCommad,
                                              " ) ) + ( middleName IN ( ",
                                              @authorFullNameCommad,
                                              " ) ) + ( lastName IN ( ",
                                              @authorFullNameCommad,
                                              " ) ) ) >=2;" );

        PREPARE selectStatement FROM @selectStatementString;
        EXECUTE selectStatement;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE selectStatement;
   END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL SimilarNames( 'Edgar Allan Poe' );
```

This solution starts by creating a `PROCEDURE` called `SimilarNames` (after `DROP`ping any existing versions of the `PROCEDURE`).  This `PROCEDURE` stores the name passed to it ( such as `'Edgar Allan Poe'`) in the parameter variable `authorFullName`.

Once begun, the `PROCEDURE` starts by converting a string such as `Edgar Allan Poe` into `'Edgar', 'Allan', 'Poe'` and storing it in the variable `@authorFullNameCommad`.

The `CONCAT()` function is then used to form the text of the SQL statement that will produce our results.  Where `authorFullName` is `Edgar Allan Poe` the following statement is produced and stored in `@selectStatementString`...

```
SELECT authorID,
       firstName,
       middleName,
       lastName
FROM author
WHERE ( ( firstName IN ( 'Edgar', 'Allan', 'Poe' ) ) + ( middleName IN ( 'Edgar', 'Allan', 'Poe' ) ) + ( lastName IN ( 'Edgar', 'Allan', 'Poe' ) ) ) >=2;
```

The SQL statement is then `PREPARE`d and `EXECUTE`d, thus producing the desired list when the `PROCEDURE` is called, which may be done using...

```
CALL SimilarNames( 'Edgar Allan Poe' );
```

Please note that you do not have to declare the `PROCEDURE` after doing so for the first time.  i.e. The following will work just fine...

```
CALL SimilarNames( 'Edgar Allan Poe' );
CALL SimilarNames( 'James Tiberius Kirk' );
```

Also, please note that this particular method *is* vulnerable to **SQL Injection**.  I can develop a version protected against that if you wish - it's just late at the moment and I will be going to bed shortly.

My statement was tested against a sample dataset created using the following script...

```
CREATE TABLE author
(
    authorID     INT   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstName    VARCHAR( 50 ),
    middleName   VARCHAR( 50 ),
    lastName     VARCHAR( 50 ),
    PRIMARY KEY ( authorID )
);
INSERT INTO author ( firstName,
                     middleName,
                     lastName )
VALUES ( 'Edgar', 'Allan', 'Poe' ),
       ( 'Poe', 'Allan', 'Edgar' ),
       ( 'Edgar', 'Poe', '' ),
       ( 'Edgar', '', 'Poe' ),
       ( '', 'Edgar', 'Poe' ),
       ( 'Allan', 'Poe', '' ),
       ( 'Edgar', 'Allan', '' ),
       ( 'Allan', 'Edgar', 'Poe' ),
       ( 'Edgar', 'Allan', 'Allan' ),
       ( 'James', 'Tiberius', 'Kirk' ),
       ( 'Karl', 'Ignatius', 'von Bach' ),
       ( 'Edgar', 'Poe', 'xyz' ),
       ( 'Allanah', 'Poelsen', '' );
```

The results were as I expected.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

**Further Reading**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/call.html (on MySQL's `CALL` statement)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat (on MySQL's `CONCAT()` function)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html (on MySQL's `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/deallocate-prepare.html (on MySQL's `DEALLOCATE` statement)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html (on MySQL's `DELIMITER` command)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-procedure.html (on MySQL's `DROP PROCEDURE` statement)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execute.html (on MySQL's `EXECUTE` statement)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in (on MySQL's `IN` operator)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html (on MySQL's `PREPARE` statement)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace (on MySQL's `REPLACE()` function)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html (on MySQL's `SET` statement)

Comment: Thank you so much. Absolutely wonderful solution and very clear explanation. But when I put the code in mysql it says: Unexpected character (near ;).

Comment: Please reproduce the full text of the error message - I'm particularly interested in other clues, such as line numbers.

Comment: Number lines are 9, 22, 24, 25, 26. I use phpmyadmin and I there's a red small icon by the line of code, and it only says: 'Unexpected character. (near ;)

Comment: Please try replacing each semicolon with a ` //`, then see what happens.

Comment: Now it says: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Comment: I'm getting an error there using `MySQL Console`.  I'll investigate.  Hopefully this won't take long.

Comment: Just before you asked me to try replacing the semicolon with //, I got the following error: and I still get it: #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now. Unrecognized keyword. (near "ON" at position 25). SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143706/discussion-between-toonice-and-xty83a).

Answer (score 3):

In any database, you can do something like this:

```
where firstName in ('Edgar', 'Allan', 'Poe') and
      middleName in ('Edgar', 'Allan', 'Poe') and
      middleName <> firstName and
      lastname in ('Edgar', 'Allan', 'Poe') and
      lastname not in (firstname, middleName)
```

This is actually pretty easy to extend to more names, if you like -- assuming the names are distinct as in your example (if you want to allow authors with duplicated names, just remove lines 3 and 5 from the above query).

However, depending on your database, you might want to use regular expressions or full text search instead.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helle_Helle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holling_C._Holling :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo . . . Your example is nicer than Sirhan Sirhan.

Answer (score 0):

For a generic DBMS, assuming your intent is just to simplify your queries, one way would be to add a separate computed column to the author table, one which is triggered on insert and update.

In other words, have a clumn called `searchFullName` and have it set to:

```
<space><firstName><space><secondName><space><lastName><space>
```

Then you query becomes a (relatively) simple:

```
select something from author
where searchFullName like '% Poe %'
  and searchFullName like '% Edgar %'
```

It won't be blindingly fast for large tables but it should achieve what you want.